# How to store different objects and keep a link between them without normalization of firebase database

Tags: android, database-design, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on hostel android app that shows a list of hostels and their available room types with images and the facilities they got.

I am trying hard to avoid normalizing the data as firebase discourages that.

Problem is I don't know how to push one distinct hostel object to firebase and keep it linked up with it's corresponding room object so that i can fetch just one hostel and it's available rooms would come with it, including the facilities they got.

This is what i'm tempted to do, but i know it's not good to nest the rooms and facilities in the hostel arrays.

```
{  
   "hostels":[  
      {  
         "name":"Frontline Hostel",
         "location":"Ayeduase",
         "policy":"Security gates close at 11 30pm ...etc",
         "views":"14",
         "frontImage":"http://someUrl",
         "roomsAvailable":[  
            {  
               "numberOfOccupants":"3",
           "price":"1800",
           "remaining":"5",
           "img1":"http://someUrl",
           "img2":"http://someUrl",
           "img3":"http://someUrl",
           "img4":"http://someUrl"
        },
        {  
           "numberOfOccupants":"3",
           "price":"1800",
           "remaining":"5",
           "img1":"http://someUrl",
           "img2":"http://someUrl",
           "img3":"http://someUrl",
           "img4":"http://someUrl"
        }
     ],
     "facilities":[  
        {  
           "shuttle":true
        },
        {  
           "security cameras":true
        },
        {  
           "free electricity":true
        }
     ]
  },
  {  
     "name":"Evandy Hostel",
     "location":"Bomso",
     "policy":"Non-residents not allowed in hostel after 11pm ...etc",
     "views":"8",
     "frontImage":"http://someUrl",
     "roomsAvailable":[  
        {  
           "numberOfOccupants":"2",
           "price":"2000",
           "remaining":"7",
           "img1":"http://someUrl",
           "img2":"http://someUrl",
           "img3":"http://someUrl",
           "img4":"http://someUrl"
        },
        {  
           "numberOfOccupants":"1",
           "price":"3500",
           "remaining":"2",
           "img1":"http://someUrl",
           "img2":"http://someUrl",
           "img3":"http://someUrl",
           "img4":"http://someUrl"
        }
     ],
         "facilities":[  
            {  
               "swimming pool":true
            },
            {  
               "gym":true
            },
            {  
               "wi-fi":true
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I need help on how to model the separate "hostel object", "room object", "facilities object" so I can add distinct hostels to firebase and be able to fetch one hostel-rooms-facilities for popuplation of views.
Plus the users wont be authenticating before using the app.
I just need a way to use my personal version to update the database and keep it up to date

Answer (score 0):

@isaacllarbi if you are using java to write this code, then i'll suggest you create different models for the respective parents node(In your case this are hostels, rooms available and facilities)
1) for the hostels class, you'll use this

`public class Hostels {
    String name, location,policy,frontImage;
    int views;

```
public Hostels(String name, String location, String policy, String frontImage, int views) {
    this.name = name;
    this.location = location;
    this.policy = policy;
    this.frontImage = frontImage;
    this.views = views;
}}`
```

add children of the hostel object by making database reference to the root. Since you are adding more than one hostels, it's important that you generate a unique id for each hostel addition

```
 private void Hostelschildren (String name, String location, String policy, String frontImage, int views) {
    Hostel host = new Hostel(name, location, policy, frontImage, views);

    mDatabase.child("Hostels").child(hostelid).setValue(host);
}
```

for the rooms Available

```
public class Roomsavailable {
String img1,img2,img3,img4;
int numberofoccupants,price,remaining;

public Roomsavailable(String img1, String img2, String img3, String img4, int numberofoccupants, int price, int remaining) {
    this.img1 = img1;
    this.img2 = img2;
    this.img3 = img3;
    this.img4 = img4;
    this.numberofoccupants = numberofoccupants;
    this.price = price;
    this.remaining = remaining;
}
```

also add children to the Rooms availale object by making database reference to the root(In this case rooms available). Since you are adding more than one rooms, it's important that you generate a unique id for each room addition

```
private void roomsdata (String img1, String img2 String img3, String img4, int numberofoccupants, int price, int remaining) {
    Roomsavailable rooms = new Roomsavailable(img1, img2, img3, img4, numberofoccupants, price, remaining);

    mDatabase.child("Hostels").child("rooms available").child(roomid).setValue(rooms);
}
```

}
and for the facilities

```
public class Facilities {
String swimmingpool, gym, wifi;

public Facilities(String swimmingpool, String gym, String wifi) {
    this.swimmingpool = swimmingpool;
    this.gym = gym;
    this.wifi = wifi;
}
```

}

finally add children to the Facilities object by making database reference to the node(In this case rooms facilities) under the hostel node.

```
 private void facilities (String gym, String swimming_pool, String wifi) {
    Facilities facili = new Facilities(gym, swimming_pool, wifi);

    mDatabase.child("Hostels").child(hostelid).child("facilities").setValue(facili);
}
```

**NOTE** the Database references and the appropriate places to add unique id's. 
I hope this was helpful please leave your comments

Comment: thanks @XY-JOE for the elaborate answer.
how do i generate the unique ids i have to pass in to keep the 3 objects(hostel, rooms, facilities) linked to each other

`mDatabase.child("Hostels").child(hostelid).setValue(host);`

                                                                                   
`mDatabase.child("Hostels").child("roomsavailable").child(roomid).setValue(rooms);`
                                                

`mDatabase.child("Hostels").child(hostelid).child("facilities").setValue(facili);`

Comment: the ID's may be anything unique either name, date or so. Since you are going to be manually storing data like you said, the ID's are meant to ensure that no new data overwrites the existing one. If you are sure the hostel names are going to be different i would suggest you use names along side date as the ID. Let me know if you can handle that or if you might need the code. By the way if the answer above was helpful, you should check it to indicate the question has been answered  @isaacllarbi